# SQL Configure Distribution Connection Issue

Tags: sql-server, replication, azure-sql-server, transactional-replication

I am trying to configure the distribution of SQL Server (2016). This is an Azure SQL VM. However, when doing so I get the following error:

```
TITLE: Configure Distribution Wizard
------------------------------

SQL Server is unable to connect to server 'COMPANY-SQL'.

SQL Server replication requires the actual server name to make a connection to the server. Specify the actual server name, ''. (Replication.Utilities)
```

(note it is not actually `COMPANY-SQL` but a similar naming format). I have tried, as suggested in many posts to `sp_dropserver` and `sp_addserver`. This successfully creates `@@SERVERNAME` set to `company-sql-2` which is the name of both my Azure resource (not sure where `COMPANY-SQL` originates). I'm lost as to how to connect here despite already being connected to the database & why the error says the actual server name is simply ''.

Answer (score 0):

> SQL Server is unable to connect to server 'COMPANY-SQL'.
>
> SQL Server replication requires the actual server name to make a connection to the server. Specify the actual server name, ''. (Replication.Utilities)

**`SERVERPROPERTY`**:  The Windows server and instance name, which together make up the specific server instance, are provided by the ServerName attribute.

**`@@SERVERNAME`**:  The name of the local server as it is set up right now is provided by @@SERVERNAME.

Run the following commands together and you will get two different names.

```sql
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY(N'servername')
SELECT @@SERVERNAME
```

then change the server name by dropping the name got by `@@SERVERNAME` command with `sp_dropserver` procedure and set name got by `SERVERPROPERTY` command with `sp_addserver` procedure then **Restart the SQL Server Service**.

Answer (score 0):

I know that's to late to answer but maybe it helps new visitors.

You should replace the SQL Server server name with the correct network name of the computer

**Let's execute this queries on master database.**

```
-- Use the Master database
USE master
GO

-- Declare local variables
DECLARE @serverproperty_servername varchar(100),
@servername varchar(100);

-- Get the value returned by the SERVERPROPERTY system function
SELECT @serverproperty_servername = CONVERT(varchar(100), SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName'));

-- Get the value returned by @@SERVERNAME global variable
SELECT @servername = CONVERT(varchar(100), @@SERVERNAME);

-- Drop the server with incorrect name
EXEC sp_dropserver @server=@servername;

-- Add the correct server as a local server
EXEC sp_addserver @server=@serverproperty_servername, @local='local';
```

That worked for me.

Reference : [MSSQLSERVER_18483](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18483-database-engine-error?view=sql-server-ver16)

And in the next step if you faced with **RegCreateKeyEx()** Error read the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55416987/how-to-fix-regcreatekeyex-returned-error-5-access-is-denied-in-sql-server)